# Beautiful Soup web crawler: Trying to filter specific rows I want to parse

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I built a web-crawler, here is an example of one of the pages that it crawls:

https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.fcgi?id=buckle002jos

I only want to get the rows that contain 'NCAA' or 'NAIA' or 'NWDS' in them. Currently the following code gets all of the rows on the page and my attempt at filtering it does not quite work.

Here is the code for the crawler:

```
''' Crawling Function '''

# Must enter the 'id' number that is at the end of a teams baseball
# reference page link in order to use this function
def crawl(_id):
    bbref = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id='
    html = sewp(bbref + _id)
    href_tags = html.find_all(href = True)
    href_tags = list(href_tags)
    hrefs = [tag.get('href') for tag in href_tags]
    
    # Append relevant links to list
    player_links = []
    for href in hrefs:
        if '/register/player.fcgi?id=' in href:
            player_links.append(href)
    
    # finish by Returning the player data to a list
    player_data = []
    for link in player_links:
        player_data.append(find_data('https://www.baseball-reference.com' + link))
    for df in player_data:
        numeric(df)
    return player_data
```

And here is the code for the function "find_data", that I crawl inside the crawler where i am trying to filter the parsed rows:

```py
def find_data(url):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    text = soup(page.text, features='lxml')
    row = text.find_all('tr')

    ''' Attempting to parse row, but only if NCAA, NAIA, or NWDS in row '''
    data = []
    for r in row:
        if 'NCAA' in r or 'NWDS' in r or 'NAIA' in r:
            data.append(parse_row(r))

            # data = [parse_row(rows) for rows in row]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
```

other functions:

```
def parse_row(rows):
    return [str(x.string)for x in rows.find_all('td')]

def numeric(frame):
    for i in frame.columns:
        try:
            frame[[i]] = frame[[i]].astype(float)
        except:
            pass
def sewp(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    html = soup(r.text, features = 'lxml')
    return html
```

below is the function that I used to do my crawl function

```
# dict of team id's for desired league by year
nwl_team_id_dict_21 = {'kokomo':'08eb649f', 'pit-spitters':'6f0d2cd3','kingfish':'79c106fa',
                       'rivets':'f61e0ce3','bombers':'3cbb765d','growlers':'b0a9f9bc','spiders':'355b5892',
                       'mallards':'8eaa34fb','chinooks':'2ffd9848','booyah':'604e6d45','bucks':'2b013943',
                       'huskies':'95a9931c','loggers':'896f45b5','express':'ee0f0409','mud-puppies':'f46a2140',
                       'rox':'0b75a745','moondogs':'7027a89b','woodchucks':'f22e21d1','rafters':'8f0328cd',
                       'stingers':'1884dcb1','honkers':'0b4021dc','larks':'5bed69fc'}

def get_league(league_dict):
    all_players = []
    for team in league_dict.values():
        all_players.append(crawl(team))
    return all_players
```

Comment: Could you paste the whole code so that it could be reproduced more easily? For example what are "headers", "sewp", etc.

Comment: I apologize, just edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what are you trying to do. In the line `if '/register/player.fcgi?id=' in href:` you are focusing only on the url with "player" in it. This returns you only the url of the current webpage, it is not really "crawling". Do you mean to find also urls with "team" in them? Because those are the URLs in the tables on that webpages..

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is excuted and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It helps to see if code works as you expect. maybe `r` has list like `["<a>NCAA</a>", ...]` and then `'NCAA' in r` will not work. And this would need to `parse_row` before checking.

Comment: Sorry @mbostic let me add some more code, then it will make more sense

Comment: Just edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense what I am trying to do. Right now this returns a list of lists, each object in the list being a team that has a list of its player data in it. But it has too much data as i only want the 'NAIA' and NCAA and NWDS rows

Comment: I used `print()` to see what `URL` it reads and what it has in rows - and it doesn't have `NAIA`  `NCAA` `NWDS` in rows because it reads from page which doesn't have `NAIA`  `NCAA` `NWDS` in HTML. So I will repeate: first debug your code because it use different values then you expect. And you should first run `r = parse_row(r)` and later check `'NCAA' in r`

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are suggesting, inside the table there are rows that have NCAA NAIA and NWDS in them. So is there a different way I should be filtering the rows? I have dataframes and have tried using iterrows to filter out the data I want

Comment: you show url with `id=buckle002jos` but code doesn't read table from this page but it find reference to other page https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.fcgi?id=gillie001cla and it reads table from this page - and this page doesn't have `NAIA NCAA NWDS`

Comment: there is difference between - `'NCAA' in ["NCAA", "OTHER"]` which gives `True` and `'NCAA' in ["<a>NCAA</a>", "<span>OTHER</span>"]` which gives `False`. But biggest problem is that code runs `find_data('https://www.baseball-reference.com' + link)` which use different url then you expect. IF you wuld use `print(url)` in `find_data()` then you would see if you search on correct page.

Comment: I The url i put as an example is just for refernece, i have all the data I want. It's just too much and i need to filter it. I have done print(url)

Comment: I will repeate: you have to use `r = parse_row(r)` before `'NCAA' in r` because this is yoru problem. You check `'NCAA' in ["<a>NCAA</a>", "<span>OTHER</span>"]` which gives `False` - but you have to check `'NCAA' in ["NCAA", "OTHER"]` to get `True`

Comment: simply run `r = parser_row(r) `before `if 'NCAA' in r or 'NWDS' in r or 'NAIA' in r:`. And later `append(r)` instead of `append(parser_row(r))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the code more efficient by letting pandas parse the table and rows and then vectorize the check as opposed to iterating through each row.

**Code:**

```
def find_data(url, includeKeywords):
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    df = df[df.stack().str.contains('|'.join(includeKeywords)).any(level=0)]
    return df

includeKeywords = ['NCAA','NWDS','NAIA']
find_data('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.fcgi?id=buckle002jos', includeKeywords)
```

**Output:**

```
   Year Age AgeDif            Tm    Lg   Lev  ...  TB  GDP  HBP  SH  SF  IBB
0  2020  19   -2.2  Grand Canyon   WAC  NCAA  ...   0  0.0    0   1   0  NaN
1  2021  20   -1.8  Grand Canyon   WAC  NCAA  ...  15  NaN    3   5   1  NaN
2  2021  20   -0.5        Kokomo  NWDS   Smr  ...  23  3.0    4   0   1  NaN

[3 rows x 30 columns]
```

**Full Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd


headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

''' Crawling Function '''

# Must enter the 'id' number that is at the end of a teams baseball
# reference page link in order to use this function
def crawl(_id):
    bbref = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id='
    html = sewp(bbref + _id)
    href_tags = html.find_all(href = True)
    href_tags = list(href_tags)
    hrefs = {tag.text:tag.get('href') for tag in href_tags}
    
    # Append relevant links to list
    player_links = {}
    for playerName, href in hrefs.items():
        if '/register/player.fcgi?id=' in href:
            player_links.update({playerName:href})
    
    # finish by Returning the player data to a list
    player_data = []
    for playerName, link in player_links.items():
        player_data.append(find_data('https://www.baseball-reference.com' + link, includeKeywords, playerName))
    for df in player_data:
        numeric(df)
    player_data = pd.concat(player_data, axis=0)
    return player_data

def find_data(url, includeKeywords, playerName):
    print(playerName)
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(axis=0, how='all')
    df = df[df.stack().str.contains('|'.join(includeKeywords)).any(level=0)]
    df['playerName'] = playerName
    return df

def numeric(frame):
    for i in frame.columns:
        try:
            frame[[i]] = frame[[i]].astype(float)
        except:
            pass
def sewp(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    html = soup(r.text, features = 'lxml')
    return html

# dict of team id's for desired league by year
nwl_team_id_dict_21 = {'kokomo':'08eb649f', 'pit-spitters':'6f0d2cd3','kingfish':'79c106fa',
                       'rivets':'f61e0ce3','bombers':'3cbb765d','growlers':'b0a9f9bc','spiders':'355b5892',
                       'mallards':'8eaa34fb','chinooks':'2ffd9848','booyah':'604e6d45','bucks':'2b013943',
                       'huskies':'95a9931c','loggers':'896f45b5','express':'ee0f0409','mud-puppies':'f46a2140',
                       'rox':'0b75a745','moondogs':'7027a89b','woodchucks':'f22e21d1','rafters':'8f0328cd',
                       'stingers':'1884dcb1','honkers':'0b4021dc','larks':'5bed69fc'}



includeKeywords = ['NCAA','NWDS','NAIA']
results = []
for team, _id in nwl_team_id_dict_21.items():
    print('\n', team.title())
    player_data = crawl(_id)
    results.append(player_data)
results = pd.concat(results, axis=0)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
      Year   Age AgeDif                 Tm    Lg  ...  H9  HR9  BB9  SO9  SO/W
0   2020.0  19.0   -2.2       Grand Canyon   WAC  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1   2021.0  20.0   -1.8       Grand Canyon   WAC  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
2   2021.0  20.0   -0.5             Kokomo  NWDS  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1   2020.0  21.0   -0.3  Embry-Riddle (FL)   SSC  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
3   2021.0  22.0    1.5             Kokomo  NWDS  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
..     ...   ...    ...                ...   ...  ...  ..  ...  ...  ...   ...
5   2022.0  22.0   -0.2         Montevallo   GSC  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
0   2020.0  22.0    1.1       Kansas State   B12  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
2   2021.0  23.0    1.6       Kansas State   B12  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
3   2021.0  23.0    2.5           Bismarck  NWDS  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
4   2022.0  24.0    2.3         New Mexico   MWC  ... NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN

[2378 rows x 52 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because you check

```
'NCAA' in ["<a>NCAA</a>", "<span>OTHER</span>"]
```

which gives `False`

It checks every element on list using `'NCAA' == "<a>NCAA</a>"` (which gives `False`), not using `'NCAA' in "<a>NCAA</a>"` (which would give `True`)

You have to first run `r = parse_row(r)` to check

```
'NCAA' in ["NCAA", "OTHER"]
```

and this will work

---

Minimal working code

```
import requests
''' Crawling Function '''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

headers = {}

def find_data(url):
        print(url)
        
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        text = soup(page.text, features='lxml')
        row = text.find_all('tr')
        
        ''' Attempting to parse row, but only if NCAA, NAIA, or NWDS in row '''
        data = []
        
        for r in row:
          r = parse_row(r)
          #print(r)
          if 'NCAA' in r or 'NWDS' in r or 'NAIA' in r:
              #r = parse_row(r)
              #print(r)
              data.append(r) 

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        return df
    
def parse_row(rows):
    return [x.string for x in rows.find_all('td')]
    #return [x.get_text() for x in rows.find_all('td')]

find_data('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.fcgi?id=buckle002jos')
```

Result:

```
   0     1             2     3     4     5   6   ...    22  23    24 25 26 27    28
0  19  -2.2  Grand Canyon   WAC  NCAA  None   4  ...  .000   0     0  0  1  0  None
1  20  -1.8  Grand Canyon   WAC  NCAA  None  32  ...  .448  15  None  3  5  1  None
2  20  -0.5        Kokomo  NWDS   Smr  None  35  ...  .512  23     3  4  0  1  None

[3 rows x 29 columns]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! Being able to read this code instead of a comment helps alot and I understand what you were trying to say now. Thank you for the help